# A Friend asking me whether it is OK to have doubts

Tags: prophet-muhammad

I have a friend who is asking whether it is ok to have doubts, I have heard people asking the following questions and never had the proper answers

How can a prophet have time to be married to 9 ladies...

How can an Aaya be corrected.. I am sure that some here will know the story "لَا يَسْتَوِي الْقَاعِدُونَ مِنَ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ غَيْرُ أُولِي الضَّرَرِ وَالْمُجَاهِدُونَ فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ بِأَمْوَالِهِمْ وَأَنْفُسِهِمْ فَضَّلَ اللَّهُ الْمُجَاهِدِينَ بِأَمْوَالِهِمْ وَأَنْفُسِهِمْ عَلَى الْقَاعِدِينَ دَرَجَةً وَكُلًّا وَعَدَ اللَّهُ الْحُسْنَى وَفَضَّلَ اللَّهُ الْمُجَاهِدِينَ عَلَى الْقَاعِدِينَ أَجْرًا عَظِيمًا"

How can prophet Mohammad (pbuh) go to Al TAEF to try to call people to Islam... Was this instructed by God or not.

How could he marry the wife of his adopted son... how could he say that god made him marry her... and how could he say when he saw her "Mashaa Allah"... is that right for a prophet to do?

How come Islam talk about الجن while they do not exist in Christianity.

How come Islam is the only religion with 5 prayers a day?

How come Quraan says "مَا نَنسَخْ مِنْ آيَةٍ أَوْ نُنسِهَا نَأْتِ بِخَيْرٍ مِّنْهَا أَوْ مِثْلِهَا ۗ أَلَمْ تَعْلَمْ أَنَّ اللَّهَ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَدِيرٌ" ...does that make sense?

how come the 2 aayas for inheritance in sorat Al Nesaa came in two different locations split... why did it not come consecutive at once... God should not wait for questions from people

how come in hadethat al efk prophet Mohammad did not know whether Aysha was guilty or not? it took few days and he did ask her to make isteghfar to Allah... is that proper? God / Gabriel should have informed him of the right answer immediately.

Quraan is very difficult for non Arab people...

how can any religion condemn the remaining 5.5 Million people, be it Islam, Christianity or Judaism?

how come that prophet Mohammad (pbuh) did not know about the poisoned food and ate it?

I try to read and study a lot about Islam, but I was not able to answer any of those questions and many more

Regards,

Comment: You should get a answer on your questions. But I think it's best that you ask one question at the time. If you cannot find these questions somewhere else here.

About the marriage, https://www.quora.com/If-the-Quran-allows-a-Muslim-man-to-keep-4-wives-why-did-Prophet-Muhammad-PBUH-have-more-than-4#ld_zbqohc_32325

Try finding an answer to your other questions, if you cannot find something, post them here, one by one.

Comment: Having doubts is ok, as else you won't ever move from one level of faith to an other. As only by clearing your doubts your faith will get stronger. The problem with your Post is that it includes lot's of different Questions if you could post them separately in as new Questions that would be much better. As they are about different topics. Also note that most of these Questions already have answers on the site so please try to find them!

Comment: I don't get your problem with "*How can an Aaya be corrected.. I am sure that some here will know the story "لَا يَسْتَوِي الْقَاعِدُونَ مِنَ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ غَيْرُ أُولِي الضَّرَرِ وَالْمُجَاهِدُونَ فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ بِأَمْوَالِهِمْ وَأَنْفُسِهِمْ فَضَّلَ اللَّهُ الْمُجَاهِدِينَ بِأَمْوَالِهِمْ وَأَنْفُسِهِمْ عَلَى الْقَاعِدِينَ دَرَجَةً وَكُلًّا وَعَدَ اللَّهُ الْحُسْنَى وَفَضَّلَ اللَّهُ الْمُجَاهِدِينَ عَلَى الْقَاعِدِينَ أَجْرًا عَظِيمًا"*" can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is normal to question when there are so many conflicts that one can see.

This we can see in many belief systems, this we can see within ourselves and this we can gain when we see what is happening in the world. This is in many ways like life, many times there are questions that bring other questions to light. Embrace what you are feeling and continue to question.

It is a good question to ask why would a man marry a young girl and have sex with her at 9 years old? How can a belief system of God look down on others based on not following their way of thinking? How does a young person growing up in the South come to think that one race is not human as we have seen in history? How can a belief system be told that the Gospels are correct but they have come to believe that Jesus never died on the cross when the Old Testament predicted it?

Why can't people learn to look at what they are told, take the time to research for themselves and then begin to question to align themselves with what God has taught.

How can Judaism not tell Jews about the prophesies of Jesus Christ and show them that the Old Testament predicted His coming?

It is my hope that you take the time to understand that when you read the Quran, there are two Qurans: the Mecca (1st Quran) - first 13 years of the Prophet, and the Medina (2nd Quran) - the next 10 years of the Prophet. This can explain why information gathered can be confusing and why what you read shows both violence and peace taught by the Prophet.

So I close with: continue to question, ask questions, and then take the time to look at other belief systems like the Christian and Judaism and approach. Compare each belief system against an outside source like science to see if you see truth.